# Scrapy.spider not following depth_limit setting

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using a basic scrapy spider for crawling website. I am giving start_urls list and expecting to get more pages crawled than the list of URLs given in start_urls.

i tried -

1. I was configuring depth_limit settings,
2. tried to change default callback(parse method) in start_requests function
3. tried adding meta-object in scrapy request with depth

but even then only the pages mentioned in start_urls are being crawled.

can someone help me in figuring out where I'm going wrong?

scrapy spider class

```
class PageScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pagescraper'

    def __init__(self, args):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        self.start_urls = args.get('start_urls', [])
        self.url = args.get('url')
        self.allowed_page_counter = itertools.count().__next__
        self.skipped_page_counter = itertools.count().__next__
        self.crawled_pages_counter = itertools.count().__next__
        super(PageScraper, self).__init__()


    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url)


    def parse(self, response):
        try:
            response_headers = response.headers.to_unicode_dict()
            content_type = response_headers.get('content-type', '')
            if "text/html" in content_type or response.body:
                scrapy_selector = Selector(response=response)
                source_data_item = ScrapyItem()
                title = scrapy_selector.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
                yield source_data_item
            else:
                self.skipped_page_counter() 

        except Exception:
            self.skipped_page_counter()
            debug_logger.error(traceback.format_exc())

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        debug_logger.info('Number of pages scraped - {}'.format(self.allowed_page_counter()))
        debug_logger.info('Number of pages skipped - {}'.format(self.skipped_page_counter()))
        spider.logger.info('Spider closed: %s', spider.name)
```

i am initiating crawler in this way

```
        from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
        args = {}
        crawl_settings = {
         'LOG_LEVEL': 'WARNING',
         'ITEM_PIPELINES': {
           'crawler.scrapers.ScrapyPageScraper.MongoPipeline': 100
          },
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT': 10,
        'DOWNLOAD_MAXSIZE': 12582912,
        'USER_AGENT': 'wer',
        'DEPTH_LIMIT': 2,
        'DEPTH_STATS_VERBOSE': True
        }
        def crawl_process(args, crawl_settings):
           process = CrawlerProcess(settings=crawl_settings)
           console_logger.info('Initiated scraping for {} 
             pages...'.format(len(args['start_urls'])))
           process.crawl(PageScraper, args)
           process.start()
       
        new_process = Process(target=self.crawl_process, args=(args, crawl_settings))
        new_process.start()
        new_process.join()
```

Comment: Spiders do not follow any URL unless explicitly told so, by yielding `scrapy.Request` objects from your callbacks.

Comment: Was able to achieve this using crawl_spider

Comment: @Satyaaditya Could you post the functional code?  I'm trying to do the same.